# onClicking on a parent div, get child value- without String manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the child-input value; from click event on its parent div-

**Dynamic HTML**

```
<div class="tableRowOdd">
  <input type="hidden" value="28"> 

  04/11/2012
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#historyContainer .tableRowOdd').live( 'click', function(e) {

     // Here I want to get the hidden-input's value directly  
     // something like- $(this+'input').val()
     console.log( $(this) );

});
```

Don't want to do string manipulation from **$(this).html()**

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#historyContainer .tableRowOdd').live( 'click', function(e) {
     console.log( $(this).find('input').val() ); // or .text()
});
```

note that this will iterate through all inputs. if you want just the first:

```
$('#historyContainer .tableRowOdd').live( 'click', function(e) {
     console.log( $(this).find('input').first().val() ); // or .text()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).find('input').val()` should return you the value.

**Note:** Use `.on` incase if you are using jQuery 1.7 or use `.delegate` for older version. `.live` is not a preferred function.

Using `.delegate` for older versions,

```
$('#historyContainer').delegate('.tableRowOdd', 'click', function(e) {
     $(this).find('input').val()
     console.log( $(this) );
});
```

Using `.on` For jQuery 1.7,

```
$('#historyContainer').on('click', '.tableRowOdd', function(e) {
     $(this).find('input').val()
     console.log( $(this) );
});
```

Comment: @BrandtSolovij Not true.. `.on` function with a specific signature will work same as `.live`. The above `.on` signature will work.

Answer (score 2):

that is possible via jQuery:

```
$('#historyContainer .tableRowOdd').live( 'click', function(e) {

     // if you have more inputs and wanna get the hidden 
     console.log( $(this).find('input[type="hidden"]').val() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this;

```
$(this).find('input').val()
```